# How to deactivate Symantec.cloud protection without it immediately reactivating?

Tags: anti-virus

I need to temporarily disable Symantec.cloud 3.0 (on Windows 10) so I can test if it is interfering with another program.

I use the client settings screen to turn off protection (whereupon I am asked how long for and I usually answer 15 minutes). The problem is the protection turns on again after only a couple of seconds.

How can I temporarily turn off Symantec.cloud protection for the chosen duration without it immediately turning back on again?

(Uninstalling is not an option at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the Symantec web management dashboard. I don't have access to one right now so I can't tell you the exact steps.

As an alternative to temporarily disabling protection, you can create a new client group in the dashboard and specify that all of the protection be disabled for members of that group. Then assign your client to that group. Once this is done, check for updates on the client workstation to force it to immediately update it's settings to match the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks. As it's a client's work PC it's probably managed by their network admin.

Comment: Oh yes. If you're not the admin then there's not anything you'll be able to do about it.